# how to limit 12 images displaying from xml file and automatically creating pages for the others

Tags: javascript, java, html, xml

I currently have a xml file that holds 10000 images that link to videos, they are currently displaying on one page. So all 10000 images are on one page. I am trying to get it so that the images only display 12 of them and then automatically creates numerous pages for the rest.

This the codes that is getting the images

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="demo"></table>
        <script>

    // Initialize
    (function() { 
        loadXMLDoc(); 
    })(); 

    function loadXMLDoc() {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          myFunction(xmlhttp);
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "amateur.xml", true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function myFunction(xml) {
      var i;
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      var table="<tr></tr>";
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("video");
      for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
        var img = x[i].getElementsByTagName("thumbnail")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var url = x[i].getElementsByTagName("url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        table += 
          "<a href='"+url+"'><img src='"+img+"'></a>";      
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }
    </script>

</div>
```

This is a sample of what the XML file looks like, it has been edited slightly as it is inappropriate for the content to be shown. The XML file is called "amateur.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<videos>
<video id="1fb853907b9ca6add9ac">
<url>a.com</url>
<categories>A</categories>
<rating>100</rating>
<title>A</title>
<tags>A;a;AB</tags>
<duration>15</duration>
<thumbnail>http://i1.cdn2a.image.phncdn.com/m=eGcE8daaaa/videos/201011/03/148553/original/12.jpg</thumbnail>

</video>
<video id="d95ebc6a75c00d9926e7">
<url>http://ab.com</url>
<categories>A;B;An</categories>
<rating>100</rating>
<title>Sie spritzt ab</title>
<tags>a;b;as;d</tags>
<duration>65</duration>
<thumbnail>http://i0.cdn2a.image..phncdn.com/m=eGcE8daaaa/videos/201102/17/160998/original/12.jpg</thumbnail>
</video>

</videos>
```

Answer (score 0):

before moving to logic, can you please put your js code at bottom of the page and put it in a separate js file if possible? This is a good practice. Now move on to algo ( I am assuming there is no incremental return from your service, i.e you will get 10000+ result at one shot )

xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("video"); length of this array will give you total number of page, say length is x so total number of page is x/12

You can now create list of page numbers ( 1,2,....n). You can use LI tag or other to dynamically create the list using javascript for loop. In the li put anchor tag for further js page change operation.

Now create an object array inside the for loop.

For first page take first 12 element and create 12 rows.

when page 2 or other is clicked you have to take the page number ( that you can get from the link text) and you have to calculate array index. ( remember for page 2 start index will be 12 and end index will be 23 and so on ) Now clear the existing rows and add the new elements. in short pageSize*( pageNum -1 ) ;

for table creation you can use any template engine (like Handlebar or other)

Comment: Im not sure what you really mean

Comment: Is that the file that you wanted

Comment: I have depicted the steps to create a pagination. let me know in which step you have doubt. One more thing your fiddle contains some links which are redirecting some sites which can contain virus. So try to remove all such link in your fiddle

Comment: This is embarrassing but I dont know how to do any of that

Comment: Is there any way you could help me mate

Comment: tell me one thing can you able to run your code? What is the error you are getting.. first try to print total number of records you are getting from the service call\

Comment: Step one  -  Print total number of records from service response

Comment: I dont know how to do that